# What is the minimum safe distance from a neutron source through the atmosphere?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

Imagine there is a source of neutrons emanating from a point in space. Maintaining line of sight, how far away from the neutron source must you be to preclude neutron poisoning if the neutrons only travel through the atmosphere?
In other words, will the atmosphere slow down neutrons enough so that they would be harmless given a certain distance from the neutron source?

Comment: Too many variables ranging from neutron energy to actual atmosphere conditions.

Comment: Assume fast neutrons and seal level atmospheric characteristics as well as average atmospheric humidity.

Comment: You’ve still left at least two major variables unspecified.

Comment: Please do share.